# How to edit a string to add a variable at a particular place in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, indices

I have a variable:

a = 2

and I have this string:

"//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_black_xl/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"

I want edit this string so I can add variable, a, at a specific place in this string, after "mzz11035_black_xl", to make the whole string look like:

"//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_black_xl_2/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"

What options do I have to achieve this goal. I know that there are some hard coded ways where I can count the characters before and after a specific place and do slicing, but I am looking for some more general method so that it would work even if the strings change a bit. eg.

"//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_blue_xl/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"

or

"//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_blue_s/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use f string or the format() function:

```
var = "_2"
f"//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_black_xl{var}/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"
```

or

```
var = "_2"
"//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_black_xl{}/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp".format(var)
```

if the position of the "mzz11035_black_xl" is changing you can do this:

```
var = "_2"
split_with =  "mzz11035_black_xl"
initial_string = "//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_black_xl{var}/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"
# split the string into two parts
split_string = initial_string.split(split_with)
#  Add the parts back with any sting in between
resulting_string = split_string[0] + split_with + var + split_string[1]
```

but in this case, you need to make sure that you have only one "mzz11035_black_xl" in your string.

---

If the string is changing but the link structure doesn't change you can try splitting with "/" (not elegant now but can be optimized)

```
var = "_2/"
split_with = "/"
initial_string = "//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_blue_s/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"
# initializing K
K = 6
# printing original string
print("The original string is : " + str(initial_string))
 
# Using split() + join()
# Split string on Kth Occurrence of Character
temp = initial_string.split(split_with)
resulting_tuple = split_with.join(temp[:K]), split_with.join(temp[K:])
# Convert to list and insert any string 
resulting_list = list(resulting_tuple)
resulting_list.insert(1,var)
# convert to string
resulting_string = ""
resulting_string = resulting_string.join(list(resulting_list))

print("Is list after Kth split is: " + resulting_string)
```

Output:

```
"Is list after Kth split is : //media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_blue_s_2/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for not being clear before. I have edited my post a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: The third method will work even if the position of the "mzz11035_black_xl" is changing or if the string is changing.  Another alternative is to split with  "/" characters.
How else is the link supposed to change?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `replace()` function.

**Syntax:**

```
string.replace(old, new, count)
```

**Parameters:**

- **old** – old substring you want to replace.
- **new** – new substring which would replace the old substring.
- **count** – the number of times you want to replace the old substring with the new substring. (Optional)

**Return Value:**

> It returns a copy of the string where all occurrences of a substring are replaced with another substring.

**Code sample:**

```
a = "2"
str_to_replace = "//media.boohooman.com/i/boohooman/mzz11035_black_xl/mens-black-man-signature-embroidered-t-shirt?$product_page_main_magic_zoom$&fmt=webp"
old = "mzz11035_black_xl"
new = "mzz11035_black_xl_{}".format(a)
str_replaced = str_to_replace.replace(old, new)
print(str_replaced)
```